# Laravel Many to Many - One Entry for all Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm looking for an efficient way to solve this:

I have a Service model that has a belongsToMany relationship to a Prog model.

```
Service Model: 

public function relatedProgs(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Prog');
}
```

On the Service form, user can attach as many Progs as they like via a multi-select with $id=>$name.  There is an option to select "ALL", which just fills in the form with all the progs in the list via jquery.  This gets silly, as there are hundreds of Progs.

Of course I don't have to add them all to the form via jquery - I can have code on the back end that would add them to the DB... but what I'd really like to do is just add a "-1" to the DB and not add all hundreds of models attached.  Keep the DB small, and then just pluck all on other pages when the relation is to -1.

Is there an easy / smart way to do this?  Without a model at id -1, it will fail as there is no -1 id for progs.  I could create a "ALL" Prog model, but this would screw up other areas obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there isn't an elegant way to do this.  Maybe someone will come along with a better answer.  For now, I'll post what I've done in case anyone in future is looking for an answer, though it seems hackish to me.

Multi-select allows users to add as many apps as they like.  This will be directly entered into the DB table prog_service using the relatedProgs->attach/sync methods like normal.

If user wants to add **all** applications in the DB (hundreds) for this service, they can click "ALL APPS" within the multi-select.  The store/update methods catch this -1 id and enter NO relations into the prog_service table, nor does the form jquery-populate the select box.  Instead, the Laravel methods simply assign a new bool field, all_progs_related on the Service model to true.

Pros:

- Reduce potentially gigantic prog_service table (though not a big deal)
- Always show current applications in DB (newly added apps would not be seen if we use the hard link via the relationship)
- Better UX: the form doesn't drop through the bottom of the screen due to hundreds of apps in an ugly multi-select

Cons:

- Hackish / non-Eloquent (can't eager load when just a boolean for all apps)
- Every piece of code that touches a service w/all apps 'attached' has to keep the logic in mind.

IE:

```
 if($service->all_progs_related)
        $appList = \App\Prog::all();
    else
        $appList = \App\Prog::whereIn('id', $service->relatedProgs->pluck('id')->get();
```